# Does somebody know why my css not working on 000webhost?

Tags: html, css

I started to write a webpage and I use 000webprog. I wrote the HTML, PHP and JavaScript and everything worked fine and now I started to write the CSS. I wrote an easy CSS and it worked, but when I upload a new version of CSS file (I'm trying to make my page responsible), the page didn't change.
When I open this CSS file to edit I saw the changes but when I open with view, I don't see any changes (in 000webhost File Manager). I opened the CSS in my page (CTR + u) but nothing changed in it.
Does somebody know why?
Thank u! <3

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: In my HTML:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/alap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">

In CSS there are:
@media and (max-width: {number}px) {}
The first (1800px) is working, the second (1600px) not, bu I copied and pasted the code.

Comment: Your CSS may be cached. Try clearing your browser's cache. If you want your users to not have to clear their cache, call your css file like so: `path/to/file/style.cc?v=2`

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/